# Diverging implicit expansion error using SortedSet

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, sortedset

I'm trying to use a code similar to

```
abstract class A[T] extends Ordered[A[T]] {
  val att:Int

  def compare(that:A[T]) = 
    if (this.att >= that.att)
       1
    else
      -1
}

class B extends A[Int] {
  val att = 1
}
```

When I try this in Scala 2.11 REPL

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet
scala> SortedSet[B]()
```

I get the following error

```
<console>:11: error: diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[B]
starting with method ordered in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
          SortedSet[B]()
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance of the `Ordering` type class to create a `SortedList`. The `ordered` method mentioned in the error message will automatically create an `Ordering[X]` for any type `X` that's an `Ordered[X]`.

Your `B` is not an `Ordered[B]`, however—it only extends `Ordered[A[Int]]`. `Ordered` is invariant in its type argument, so `Ordered[B]` and `Ordered[A[Int]]` have essentially nothing to do with each other.

You can address this issue with [*F*-bounded polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification):

```
abstract class A[T, S <: A[T, S]] extends Ordered[S] {
  val att: Int

  def compare(that: S)= 
    if (this.att >= that.att)
      1
    else
      -1
}

class B extends A[Int, B] {
  val att = 1
}
```

Now `B` extends `Ordered[B]` and you can create the sorted set. 
Alternatively, you could use your original code and just create a `SortedSet[A[Int]]`. It's a much better idea to avoid `Ordered` altogether, though, and just define the `Ordering` type class instance directly.